# fixed position div below relative position

Tags: html, css

There are many questions like this on stackoverflow, but all of the ones that I checked asked the exact opposite of my question.
I have a fixed position div and a relatively positioned span:

```
<div class="head-wrap">
...
</div>
....
<span class="img-desc" id="main">HTML Lesson - Part 1</span>
```

CSS:

```
.img-desc {
    position:relative;
    background:rgba(5,1,20,.8);
    color:yellow;
    padding:15px;
}
#main {
    top:-150px;
    left:8px;
    font-size:2.4em;
    z-index:2 !important;
}
.head-wrap {
    z-index:50;
}
```

From what I have read, the fixed-position div is supposed to pass over the relative-positioned span. However it doesn't! How can I make the div pass over the span, instead of the other way around. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/jco7tgrv/).

Comment: `z-index` only applies to elements with a position value of anything **other** than `static`.

Comment: That's the default positioning...so, they do if you haven't set something else..Try `position:relative`.

Comment: Your fiddle has code that is significantly different than in your question (your fiddle doesn't have any elements with the id "main", and no CSS rules for one either). Would you mind clarifying what problem in your fiddle you're trying to fix?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister, I haven't updated my fiddle in a while, you probably are seeing an old version. Either way, I accidentally deleted the line that gave the `position:absolute;` to the header :)